# Populate hasAndBelongsToMany in strongloop initialization

Tags: javascript, rest, initialization, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm trying to poulate my Strongloop models and relations during startup. I've created a js-script in `server/boot/` but **how do I initialize a hasAndBelongsToMany relation?**

This is what my current setup code looks like (some parts omitted for brevity):

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.dataSources.mySqlDb.automigrate(['X', 'Y'], function(err) {
    app.models.X.create([{ fuu: "bar"}, (some more...)], function(err, xs) {});
    app.models.Y.create([{ foo: "baz"}, (some more...)], function(err, ys) {});
  });
};
```

In the X model (x.json) there is a `hasAndBelongsToMany` relation defined to Y, but how and where can I add data to it?

Comment: yes docs are silent on how to do this.  it's also broken I believe and not working.

Comment: you can insert data and then in the callbacks update the necessary relations via the node api that is generated but I found it very difficult to maintain, I ended up inserting test data directly into the db